# Проблема сетевого подключения в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, администрирование

На рабочем ноутбуке установлена ubuntu 14.04. С недавнего времени стали появляться проблемы с открытием страниц в браузерах, причем во всех. При этом пинги проходят ко всем ресурсам одинаково хорошо. Файерволов никаких не настраивал, поэтому сейчас не представляю даже в чем может быть проблема. Может кто посоветует в какую сторону копать.
UPD. Проблема наблюдается только при запросах по 80 и 443 портам (http(s)).

Comment: `Проблема только с 80 и 443 портами по tcp` -   
Это следовало в вопросе указать, не поздно его обновить. Возможно имеет место, криво настроенный, прозрачный прокси у провайдера, сегодня им роскомнадзор вставляет за фильтрацию запрещенных сайтов, вот и стараются.

Comment: К роскомнадзору отношения не имею, ибо страна другая, на провайдера тоже не грешу, т.н. виндовс проблем таких не имеет

Comment: Тогда ещё варианты: 1) глючит Firefox (гадаю на кофейной гуще, т.к. подробности не указаны) рекомендую отключить все дополнения, некоторые из них включают принудительное проксирование - из-за чего может глючить. 2) глючит  DNS, следует проверить его работу.

Comment: Firefox или Chrome - разницы нет. А проблема оказалось в dns от гугла, почему-то он у меня частенько глючил. Сменил на другой и все полетело. Спасибо, что натолкнули на правильную мысль

Answer (score 1):

Копать в сторону провайдера и маршрутизатора.

Comment: Провайдер не причастен, т.к. windows на этом же ноутбуке таких проблем не имеет. Думаю, маршрутизатор так же. Мне кажется с осью что-то не так

Comment: Ну тогда диагностикой заниматься. Во время проблем смотреть traceroute до проблемного хоста, nslookup, ping по доменному имени, а не по ip адреса, статус файерволла можно посмотреть так: sudo ufw status verbose .

Comment: Я писал, что при этом пинги проходят ко всем ресурсам одинаково хорошо. Трассировка тоже в порядке. Проблема только с 80 и 443 портами по tcp.

Comment: А браузеры какую ошибку выдают?

Comment: В браузерах просто после длительного таймаута просто пишет "Веб-страница недоступна". При попытках загрузить что-либо с помощью wget просто висит ожидание ответа